# How do i get error from ViewModel on API Call in Activity?

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java2, rx-android, android-viewmodel

When I use ViewModel in Android, I used two MutableLiveData objects in my ViewModel class.

```
var imageList: MutableLiveData<List<HitsItem>> = MutableLiveData()
var errorMessage: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
```

What I want is whenever an error occurs in API Call errorMessage is set, similarly, when API call is a success, imageList is set.

How can I check API is a success or not in Activity, I want a Toast error message in Activity when API Call is not success..?

ImageViewModel.kt

```
fun getImages(): LiveData<List<HitsItem>> {
    imageList = MutableLiveData()
    loadImages()
    return imageList
}

fun loadImages() {
    val api = PexelClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    val imageObservable = api.images
    imageObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .map({ result -> result })
        .subscribe(
            Consumer<ImageModel> { this.handleResults(it) },
            Consumer<Throwable> { this.handleError(it) }
        )
}

private fun handleResults(list: ImageModel) {
    imageList.value = list.hits
    errorMessage.value = null
}

private fun handleError(t: Throwable) {
    imageList.value = null
    errorMessage.value = t.message
}
```

Activity

```
lateinit var imagesViewModel:ImagesViewModel
lateinit var adapter:ImageAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mvvm_rx_retrofit)


    rv_images.setHasFixedSize(true)
    rv_images.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    imagesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ImagesViewModel::class.java)
    imagesViewModel.getImages().observe(this, object : Observer<List<HitsItem>> {
        override fun onChanged(imageList: List<HitsItem>?) {
            if(imageList != null){
                adapter = ImageAdapter(this@MvvmRxRetrofit,imageList)
                rv_images.adapter = adapter
            }
        }
    })


}
```

Comment: make handleResults, handleError in methos in activity instead of viewmodel

Comment: Still, how do I get both results, error and list in Activity

Comment: 1. Don't do `imageList = MutableLiveData()` in `getImages()` function. 2. Make the livedatas be val instead of var. 3. Observe `errorMessage` too in your activity like you're observing `imageList` through `getImages()`. 4. Don't send null to error when you have data `errorMessage.value = null`. And don't send null to data when you have error `imageList.value = null`. Remove these

Comment: Thank you, but can you show me how I get **errorMessage** in Activity with a sample code

Answer (score 2):

1. **Create a Network Response class**:

public class AsyncResponse {

```
public ResponseStatus responseStatus ;
public Throwable error ;
public JsonElement data ;


AsyncResponse(ResponseStatus responseStatus, JsonElement data ,Throwable error){
    this.responseStatus = responseStatus ;
    this.data = data ;
    this.error = error ;
}

public static AsyncResponse loading(){
    return new AsyncResponse(ResponseStatus.LOADING,null,null);
}

public static AsyncResponse success(JsonElement data){
    return new AsyncResponse(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS,data,null);
}

public static AsyncResponse error(Throwable error){
    return new AsyncResponse(ResponseStatus.ERROR,null,error);
}
```

}

2. **Create a enum class**:

   public enum ResponseStatus {
        LOADING,SUCCESS,ERROR 
   }
3. **In you viewmodel class, wherever you receive a response, just post the value:**

   private MutableLiveData asyncResponseMutableLiveData
   = new MutableLiveData<>();

   Response success:

   asyncResponseMutableLiveData.postValue(AsyncResponse.success());

   Response error:

   asyncResponseMutableLiveData.postValue(AsyncResponse.error(new Throwable(e)));

**4. In Activity Class, observe the response**

```
 mChatDialogViewModel.getResponse().observe(this, new Observer<AsyncResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
                if (asyncResponse != null)
                    consumeResponse(asyncResponse);
            }
        });

private void consumeResponse(AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {

        switch (asyncResponse.responseStatus) {

            case LOADING: {
                break;
            }
            case SUCCESS: {

                break;
            }
            case ERROR: {

                break;
            }
            default:
                break;

        }
```